# xPages and AngularJS - namespace prefix in tags attributes causes errors in DDE

Tags: xpages

I would like to use AngularJS http://www.angularjs.org in my xPages app but I found a strange problem that syntaxt, that Angular is using, colides with xPages. Angular adds special tag attributes that are commands for angular engine/compiler. Typicly Angular uses attributes with 'ng'  namespace. e.g.

```
<div ng:app="" ng:controller="">
... content here ...
</div>
```

When I put these attributes into xPages, editor raises it as an error because there is no such 'ng' namespace defined. The when I define this namespace in xPage  tag, there is no error in DDE but Domino removes this 'ng' prefix from attributes names, so things do not work and I'm getting this outpput in browser:

```
<div app="" controller="">
... content here ...
</div>
```

Is there a way, how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the xpages source code generator is removing the prefixes, if you have 8.5.3, you can do this.

```
<xp:panel tagName="div">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="ng:app" value="test"></xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="ng:controller" value="test"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:panel>
```

If you are not on 8.5.3 yet, you would have to do something like this:

```
<xp:text escape="false">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "<div ng:controller='test' ng:app='test' >"; }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
    <xp:text escape="false">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "</div>"; }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

Comment: I just dont undestand whats going on here at all. AnguralJS's latest snapshot supports alternative syntaxt using attributes like ng-app="" instead of ng:app="" Ok so I'm trying  this on my xpages(using Domino 8.5.3) and Domino removes some attributes completely. I have a simple html on xPage `<div ng-app='' ng-controller='AppCtrl'></div>` but in browser I'm getting `<div  ng-controller='AppCtrl'></div>`  no ng-app='' there. Simply removed only because it is empty??  I xpages touches my code????

Comment: David, When you write <div ng-app='' ng-controller='AppCtrl'></div>  Xpages Generates Java code that will then render the html to the webpage that looks like this:          private UIComponent createDiv(FacesContext context, 
                UIComponent parent, PageExpressionEvaluator evaluator) {
            UIPassThroughTag component = new UIPassThroughTag();
            component.setTag("div");
            component.addAttribute("ng-app", "");
            component.addAttribute("ng-controller", "AppCtrl");
            return component;
        }  It won't work with the attribute empty.

Comment: It assumes if its empty you don't need it

Comment: The XML of a .xsp file is just an instruction set for Designer to generate the Java code to which Toby refers. If you define your own components and renderers, you have full control over the markup sent to the browser. The native components are just a convenience for people who don't want to write all the Java code themselves.

Answer (score 0):

From the xpage bible:

"To use the new ui component , you need to extend the current set of xpages control tags'. To do this specify a new tag name as part of the component definition in an xsp.config file"

```
<faces-config>
 <faces-config-extension>
   <namespace-uri>...</namespace-uri>
   <default-prefix>...</default-prefix>
 </faces-config-extension>
</faces-config>
```

I never did add such a library but maybe this helps